# Pytorch custom dataset is super slow

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

During training it takes ages to load one batch of data. What can cause this problem?
I am new to Pytorch, i had been working with tensorflow for a while, this my first attempt to create something like this.
I wrote a custom dataset which gets its images from folders, it gets stored in a dataframe which will be splited it into train val sets.

```
class CustomDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
def __init__(self, root, split, train_ratio = 0.85, val_ratio = 0.1, transform=None):
    self.root = root

    self.train_ratio = train_ratio
    self.val_ratio = val_ratio
    self.test_ratio = 1 - (self.train_ratio + self.val_ratio)

    df = self.folder2pandas()
    self.split = split 
    self.data = self.splitDf(df)
    self.transform = transform

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.data)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    row = self.data.iloc[[idx]]

    x = row.values[0][0]
    y = row.values[0][1]

    x = cv2.imread(x)

    if self.sourceTransform:
        x = self.sourceTransform(x)

    return x, y

def folder2pandas(self):
    tuples = []
    for folder, subs, files in os.walk(self.root):
        for filename in files:
            path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, filename))
            tuples.append((path, folder.split('\\')[-1]))
    return pd.DataFrame(tuples, columns=["x", "y"])

def splitDf(self, df):
    df = df.sort_values(by=['x'], ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
    train_idxs = df.loc[range(0, int(self.train_ratio * len(df)))]
    val_idxs = df.loc[range(int(self.train_ratio * len(df)),
                            int(self.train_ratio * len(df)) + int(self.val_ratio * len(df)))]
    test_idxs = df.loc[range(
        int(self.train_ratio * len(df)) + int(self.val_ratio * len(df)), len(df))]

    if self.split == 'train':
        return train_idxs
    elif self.split == 'val':
        return val_idxs
    elif self.split == 'test':
        return test_idxs
```

Augmentations:

```
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
transforms.Resize((224,224)),
transforms.RandomChoice([
    transforms.RandomAutocontrast(),
    transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.3, contrast=0.5, saturation=0.1, hue=0.1),
    transforms.GaussianBlur(kernel_size=(5,5), sigma=(0.1, 2.0)),
    transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=3),
    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(),]),
transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(0.5),
transforms.ToTensor(), 
transforms.Normalize(res[0].numpy(), res[1].numpy()),                                  
])

val_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224,224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(), 
    transforms.Normalize(res[0].numpy(), res[1].numpy()),                                  
])
```

Initializing datasets:

In 'resources' folder there are two folder which name's represents the labels (BinaryClassification).

```
train_set=CustomDataset(root="resources/",split='train', transform=train_transforms)
val_set=CustomDataset(root="resources/",split='val', transform=val_transforms)
```

Giving datasets to dataloader:

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set, shuffle = True, batch_size=32, num_workers=4)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_set, shuffle = True, batch_size=32, num_workers=4)
```

Comment: Does it take time to load each batch or the first one ?

Comment: @PlainRavioli even 12 minutes wasn't enough to load the first batch...

Comment: Are you on Windows ? Also, could you put some `print`  in the `__getitem__()`  method so we can see what step is exactly taking some time ?

Comment: @PlainRavioli Yes i am on windows. I tired printing from getitem, but nothing showed up like i the function wasn't called.

Comment: Ok so you can create the instace of your dataloader, but once you try getting the first batch, it is very long right ? Can you try removing the `num_workers` parameter in the `Dataloader` creation et try again ? Something like this happened to me once, workers were very long to create on Windows, but here you only have 4  that is weird

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution! By removing num_workers dataloader can load the batches.

Comment: I have put a cleaner answer to make the post useful :) Can you mark the topic as solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the solution of the comments in a cleaner way:

The creation of several workers was taking large amount of time. It seems that on windows the creation of processes can have weird behaviours in terms of time.

As `__getitem__()` is not called, the problem is not in data loading per se, try removing the `num_workers` parameters.

```
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_set, shuffle = True, batch_size=32)
```

Then if this works, try increasing it and check the behaviour.